# volume of a cube

Tags: differential-geometry

Please, can you help me with this problem? Let $4e^{1}\wedge e^{2}\wedge e^{3}$ be a volume form on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $C=\{(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})\in \mathbb{R}^{3}:0\le a_{i}\le1\}$; can somebody, please, explain to me how can I calculate the volume of $C$, raported to that volume form?Thank you very much! I forgot to mention that $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\}$ is an ortonormated base in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\{e^{1},e^{2},e^{3}\}$ is the dual of this base. I lack theory on this subject and I am completely stuck..

Comment: I know there is a formula, but I dont know it..

Comment: Must I use an integral to calculate that volume?

Comment: Looking at your other question, I just wanted to suggest looking through the question guidelines (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question). Being polite isn't enough, you have to show context and effort you have tried on this question.

Comment: I can't help you with this question - just wanted to suggest tips to become a better user

Comment: I cant show what I have tried, because I was not given any formula or help with this..I studied alone and I think that the volume is calculated using an integral or a formula with the wedge product, which I dont know. At the other question, if you looked carrefully, I showed what I have tried.

Comment: Also, I asked some help, not the entire solution.

Comment: In your other question, when you didn't know the sign you should check case by case to see which sign it is. There are other ways to make your question better other than context: adding where you got the problem from, or your motivation from studying this.

Comment: If you know that you are completely stuck on this question, why don't you just say so in the question itself? It is generally a bad idea to give comments as clarification, if you don't show enough effort in providing details, no one will be bothered to answer.

Comment: If you don't like the strict rules of MSE, there are many sites you can post on, such as Quora.

Comment: Sorry, I will specify now that I dont know how to solve it at all..sorry!

Comment: No problem, it might help to read the help pages. MSE is not for everyone, and sometimes it might even turn new users away because of all the downvotes. Keep working hard on answering and asking good questions, and your reputation will rise up almost immediately.